# Difference between tf.nn.leaky_relu and tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I understand that `tf.nn.leaky_relu` is used to compute the function while `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU` is the layer version. But how would they differ while adding to a Functional API neural network model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go [deep enough](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4718), you might find that `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU` is actually calling `tf.nn.leaky_relu` under the hood.

Therefore, I don't think there should be any difference in using the latter or former.

Although, from my experience I would suggest to stick with Keras Layers as much as possible, if you are using Keras API, to avoid any serialization issues later on.